# Empty folders after NTFS file system recovery

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, ntfs, data-recovery, testdisk

I used TestDisk to restore a "quick formatted" drive. When the software asked something about differing MFTs, I selected to copy the MFT backup. Now I've realized that whole directory branches are missing (like everything under `bar` in `/foo/bar/xxx/xxx/`).

When I select the drive in TestDisk, I see the following:

```
Hidden sectors are present.

size       312579695 sectors
user_max   312579695 sectors
native_max 312581808 sectors
dco        312581808 sectors
Host Protected Area (HPA) present.
```

While doing a deeper search, I see the following:

```
HPFS - NTFS              0   1  1 19455 254 63  312560577
Warning: Incorrect number of heads/cylinder 0 (FAT) != 255 (HD)
Warning: Incorrect number of sectors per track 0 (FAT) != 63 (HD)
  FAT32                    0   1  1     0   0 63          0
```

The FAT32 is probably the empty file system I had created by accident and deleted while trying to recover the NTFS one. It's missing from the final result:

```
Disk /dev/sda - 160 GB / 149 GiB - CHS 19457 255 63
Current partition structure:
     Partition                  Start        End    Size in sectors

 1 * HPFS - NTFS              0   1  1 19455 254 63  312560577
```

Unfortunately I had used some MB on the partly recovered drive before I dismounted it. I didn't do an image copy, but I made a backup with the list of partitions:

```
Disk /dev/sda - 160 GB / 149 GiB - CHS 19457 255 63
     Partition               Start        End    Size in sectors
>* HPFS - NTFS              0   1  1 19326 106 48  310478853
 * HPFS - NTFS              0   1  1 19455 254 63  312560577
```

I can't find the missing files with the `P: list files` option on either selection. (The option itself is only visible when I select the second one.) How could I get back those files? The Undelete function doesn't see them. I've lost heaps of important files including a lot of GPX (Guitar Pro) from the less common types. I'm on Linux now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to get back the missing files was to use a commercial software from Windows.

1. Create a disk image on a removable drive from Linux (without mounting the damaged file system).
2. Recover the file structure from the image with [GetDataBack](http://www.runtime.org).
3. Copy back the recovered files to their original location.
4. Rebuild `grub.cfg` with `update-grub`. (I still had a working Linux on a different drive.)

`CHKDSK` run automatically and I could boot my original Windows setup.